Having trouble performing MLE calibration for geometric OU process
 def mle_calibration(self):
        #Computing probability of p2 being where it is given parameters and p1
        def likelihood_next_point(p_t, p_tm1, theta, mu, sigma):
            x = (p_t-p_tm1-theta*(mu-p_tm1)*self.dt)/(sigma*p_tm1*np.sqrt(self.dt))
            return np.exp(-x**2/2)/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
        def total_likelihood(params):
            # product = 1
            theta, mu, sigma = params
            total = 0
            for t in range(1, len(self.times)):
                total += np.log(likelihood_next_point(self.prices[t], self.prices[t-1], theta, mu, sigma))
                # product *= likelihood_next_point(self.prices[t], self.prices[t-1], theta, mu, sigma)
            return -total #take negative product so that minimization actually maximizes
        res = minimize(total_likelihood, (self.guess_theta, self.guess_mu, self.guess_sigma))
        return res.x

Here's the relevant code that is performing my MLE calibration, but I'm fairly certain I haven't done it correctly as it is spitting out absurd values such as mu = 5335, sigma = 582, fitted over natural gas price spot data over the past few years. The original guess used is theta = 0.1, mu = 10, and sigma = 0.2. Haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

Is MLE not maximum likelihood estimation? If it is, the term calibration (and the tag) is entirely superfluous.
